# Under Uniform Convergence Can you Bring an Integral Inside a Double Sum

Tags: calculus, summation

Let's say that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n(x)$ are both uniformly convergent and that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}a_n(x)dx<\infty$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}b_n(x)dx<\infty \forall n$. Obviously with each individual sum I can switch the integral and sum, but is it true, under these conditions, that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_n(x)b_m(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} a_n(x)b_m(x)dx$. I think it should be true, since for large n you should be able to bound the integral by a small epsilon amount and then take the integral into the remaining finite sum due to linearity, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_n=a_n\sum_m b_m$. Since $\sum_n a_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent, so is $\sum_n u_n(x)$.

Hence, $\int\sum_n u_n(x)dx=\sum_n\int u_n(x)dx=\sum_n\int \sum_ma_n(x)b_m(x)dx$. Since $\sum_m b_m(x)$ is uniformly convergent too and $\int a_n(x)dx<\infty$, so will be $\sum_m a_n(x)b_m(x)$.

Thus $\int\sum_n\sum_m a_n(x) b_n(x)dx=\sum_n\sum_m\int a_n(x)b_m(x) dx$

*PS : I'm not 100% sure of everything I've written though, if you find any error please tell me.*